# KiCad: can I give different names to different parts of the same net?

Tags: kicad, autorouter

Is it possible to give different names to different parts of the same net in KiCAD?

I'm setting up to do an autorouted layout (yes, I know, autorouters are evil, but they save a lot of time and should work fine for my large, but simple, design) where there are many sections of the board that need very different trace widths.  For example, a high current line runs through a resistive divider and the current is measured by an ADC.  The high current section of the net needs to be a wide trace, but the ADC measurement section does not.

The way to tell the autorouter about trace widths is through the Net Classes Editor in Design Rules.  I'm looking for a way to break a net into two, but still maintain connectivity.  I guess this would be a 2 terminal device in eeschema schematic that splits the nets, but it has no footprint and doesn't show up at all in pcbnew layout.

Is this possible and does it exist?  Is there a better way to tell an auto-router about nets that will need multiple trace widths?  In know I can do it by hand, but the simple drive circuit is repeated many times and I really don't want to hand route this board.  If it can't be done, then I guess I'll just leave all of the traces on a given net at the large size and deal with the larger board.

Comment: Its quite common to route the critical traces yourself then let the autorouter take care of the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a part out of two connected SMT pads, and connect it between two parts of a net. Each pad will be a different port, and thus will allow you to change the net, but the part itself will just be a small rectangle on the board between different trace widths (i.e. a short). If possible, remember to take the solder mask regions out of the footprint (so that the entire footprint gets solder mask).